# JsonConverter null the whole model

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a model that I'm using in a webApi. My model is as follows.

```
public class Model: IModel
{
    public string Data1 { get; set; }

    public string Data2 { get; set; }

    public int DataInt { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConcreteTypeConverter<MyObject>))]
    public List<IMyObject> DataObjects { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

In order to Deserialize that interface I created my own jsonConverter class as follows.

```
public class JsonConcreteTypeConverter<TConcreteType>: JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize<TConcreteType>(reader);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        bool result;

        if (objectType == typeof(MyObject))
        {
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And this is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/{ObjectId}/Action")]
public IHttpActionResult RunAsyncAction([FromBody] Model action)
{
    IModel modelAction = action;
    //Other code
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, OPERATION_ACCEPTED_MESSAGE);
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that when I use this jsonConverter the serializer can't deserialize Model and when I call the webApi I get null inside the "action" object that I get FromBody. If I remove the JsonConverter I get all serialized correctly except the interface that is null because serializer can't deserialize it. Jsons are correctly formatted in the call. Thank you

Comment: What is the point for generic converter, if you don't use the type provided?

Comment: @kiziu I corrected the code, it was an error pasting the code now the code is as it's in the question. The Deserialize is returning null

Comment: You still have an error in `CanConvert`, but that does not matter now. Is there anything out of the ordinary with you serialization process? I serialized `Model` with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and it works fine (I just created some dummy `IMyObject` and `MyObject`). What I can also say right now is that your `JsonConverter` won't work as you planned - it does not apply to the item in the collection, but the whole collection (to the property that is marked with attribute).

Comment: @kiziu Serialization is working fine. My problem is with Deserialization.

serializer.Deserialize<TConcreteType>(reader);

It's always returning null

Comment: Well, you said that serialization does not work also. I will investigate deserialization some more.

Comment: @kiziu Sorry I think that I need some more coffee thanks for your time

Comment: One more question, so I get the solution right. Will that `JsonConcreteTypeConverter` be always applied to a list? Because, as I said, converter has to work on specific type. List is also problematic, as it is not covariant and it makes assignments harder to generalize. Can the converter be made for `List<T>`?

Comment: @kiziu In this case is a List but in the future can be out of the list. But in 90% of the cases will be in a List<T> I'm thinking that the problem for sure will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You implementation of `JsonConverter` is not working as expected, as your `ReadJson()` is trying the deserialize a single instance from `reader`, but in fact `reader` is at the position of `ArrayStart`, so it means that converter should handle the deserialization of the whole array, not just single item. In other words - `JsonConverter` must handle deserialization of the type of decorated member.

In your case you want the converter to be used for array item. To make it work properly, you need to use different attribute - `JsonProperty`, and its property `ItemConverterType`. Result would like like this:

```
[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JsonConcreteTypeConverter<MyObject>))]
public List<IMyObject> DataObjects { get; set; }
```

This will correctly apply your converter while deserializing an item, not the whole array.

Also, if you could elaborate, what is the point of having interface in the `Model`, if your deserializer can handle only one implementation of it?

You should also correct this condition `if (objectType == typeof(MyObject))` - it should use`TConcreteType`.

PS. Regarding the comments - initially I wanted to make the `JsonConverter` work with the list because I forgot about `JsonProperty.ItemConverterType`, which is the correct way in your case.

Comment: I have the interface in the model because we have multiple implementations for that Interface. I'm developing my webApi in an iterative way and the first implementation is supporting only that type. In my next steps it will support more types. Thank you for your time it's working properly